# Adding supervisor and other info into bookdown pdf_book

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown, pdflatex

I want to include my supervisor's name, course name etc. for my paper written in bookdown. I specifically want this information to be in different lines. So far I have tried this in the yaml:

```
--- 
title: "Term Paper Title"
author:
        - "Bird"
        - "Supervisor: Hummingbird"
        - "Course: Ornithology"
        - "University: XXX State University"
date: "Summer Semester: 2021"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
documentclass: book
classoption: openany
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
mainfont: Times New Roman
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: "left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm"
linestretch: 1.5
toc-depth: 1
secnumdepth: 1
---
```

Result looks like this:

[image]

Here my name and supervisor names etc. all are in one line. How can I force them to be in different lines? For example I want something like [this](https://eddjberry.netlify.app/img/thesis_title_page.pdf) (taken from [this post](https://eddjberry.netlify.app/post/writing-your-thesis-with-bookdown/))

Comment: You could also check this template: https://github.com/ulyngs/oxforddown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a "[line block](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#line-blocks)" should do the trick:

```yaml
author: |
  | Bird
  | Supervisor: Hummingbird
  | Course: Ornithology
  | University: XXX State University
```